# сайт на nodejs с выделенным ip

Tags: node.js

На локальной машине есть сайт на node.js, который запускается через консоль(через node server.js, через localhost:3000).
Так же на ней есть динамический ip, через который я запускаю другой сайт и могу просматривать его через Интернет. Вопрос в том, как настроить сайт, который на nodejs, так, чтобы я мог просматривать его также как и остальные(через openserver например), через выделенный ip.
Спасибо.